# Secure Websockets not working on iphone browsers

Tags: javascript, php, ios, iphone, websocket

I have made the setup of websockets on nginx server.

I am using the javascript websockets in my project over SSL.

They are working fine on desktop browsers, android browsers and blackberry browsers. But they are not working on the iPhone browsers.

I have also checked the compatibility of iPhone browsers. I have tested in the safari and chrome on iPhone.

Please Help Me for any solution.

Comment: Self-signed certificate?

Comment: its not a self-signed certificate, its a purchased one.

Comment: I'm having the same issue using AWS, all platforms except iOS seem to work just fine.  I too have a purchased SSL certificate, however, I haven't configured in intermediaries - I don't see that option in AWS.

Comment: have you ever able to resolve this issue? I am having same issue with purchased certificate.